# affine arbitrage free class of nelson siegel yield curve

Tags: fixed-income, yield-curve, term-structure

I'm studying statistics for finance at university.

Last week i read the working paper on **"The Affine Arbitrage-Free Class of Nelson-Siegel Term Structure Models"**.

I would like to reproduce in R this work but i'm not able to understand the state space form of equations.

How can i estimate term adjustment?

Comment: Why not write out the state space form of equations so that people can quickly understand your problem? We do not expect people will go to all details of a paper which may not be handily available.

Comment: i'm sorry. the measurement equation is :

Comment: yt = A + BXt + εt.    y is a vector Nx1 of observed yield, A is a Nx1 vector of adjustment term, B is matrix Nx3 of this form:  1   (1−e−λτ)  ((1−e−λτ)−e−λτ) where lambda is a parameter to estimate and tao is the Maturity. X is the state variables. The state equations is:

Comment: Xt = (I − exp(−K * ∆t))*θ + exp(−K *∆t)*Xt−1 + ηt where I is diagonal matrix of 1, K is a non- diagonal matrix of parameters to estimate, θ is a vector Nx1 of parameters to estimate and ∆t is the time to maturity. i hope that you can understand, if you need more information write me. thank you so much @Gordon

Comment: Comments are meant to be temporary, can you edit the formulae into the question itself using $\LaTeX$?